# Excel vba userform crashes excel when opened

Tags: vba, excel, crash, userform

I have a userform on my spreadsheet which crashes excel and shows an Excel "System error &h8000ffff (-2147418113)" error message if I open the uf after copying and pasting data to several sheets. However if I open the uf immediately after opening the file it doesn't crash Excel. There is no code in the init function or any add-ins. I think the problem could be due to the data copy/analyze/paste functions which repeatably update a few tables, they run ok if i activate the sheet to be updated, but also crash Excel if i don't. The spreadsheet has a RTD feed and uses a class module to manage the tables. Could this be "unresolved ranges/links" or something similar?

```
Sub OPEN_CONTROL_PANEL_USERFORM()
    ufCONTROL_PANEL.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'code commented out
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running the free [VBA Code Cleaner](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm) in case there's an issue with the VBA. It exports all the modules, deletes them from the project and then re-imports them which fixes some subtle issues like this. It's also a great way of exporting code modules for use with source code control.

I've used it a lot and recommend it.

Comment: Thanks this sounds very likely. I'll give it a try.

Comment: That seems to have sorted out the small illogical bugs. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: *Caveat:* As mentioned at the cited link, the VBA Code Cleaner DOES NOT support 64-bit versions of Excel